# Can my history be tracked if I'm connected to my cellular data instead of wifi

Tags: wireshark

If my phone is using its cellular data instead of being connected to wifi, can wireshark still see what I'm doing?

Comment: You need to be more clear on your question - specifically where is wireshark running ?

Answer (score 0):

If wireshark is available for your phone and wireshark is installed on your phone you can monitor mobile data provided its not encrypted this may require your mobile to be rooted. If you have wireshark on your computer and are looking to see what your accessing on your mobile. For educational purposes only: You would need a 3g/4g jammer and also a usb 2g transceiver. You would also need cracking tools to break encryption on 2g. Hacking/Breaking mobile data encryption is most likely illegal in your country so keep that in mind. Once you have encryption key you can use that key in wireshark to decrypt data being send across the network between mobile and mobile radio tower. If you have money you could also setup a cellular base station the base station would have to be giving out a stronger signal than the real base station for device to connect if this is the case a attacker could preform a mitm attack on the mobile user.